# Mongoose isModified, what exactly is it checking?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have seen this exact `isModified` check or similar a lot upon searching, looked at Mongoose's documentation, and I can't seem to wrap my head around what exactly is its purpose or inclusion.

The first scenario I thought of was perhaps the check is for if the user was trying to reset their password and the check is to see if the "new password" matched the "db password," but that didn't make sense because the password would be stored as a hash. So now I'm at a loss.

```
schema.pre("save", async function(next) {

  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    return next();
  }


  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    this.password = hashedPassword;
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It detects whether the path **changed** and returns true/false. As example showed, this works only if you modify the mongoose object using `set`, it doesn't work when you use `UpdateOne` or `UpdateMany` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-isModified

Using your presave hooked

```
let doc = await model.FindOne({})
doc.set("username", "john")
doc.save() // isModified('password') returns false


doc.set("password", "newpassword")
doc.save() // isModified('password') returns true
```

In your presave hooked, your hook check if you set a new password, and if you did, they hash the password and update the password field with a hash of the new password

e.g.

```
doc.set("password", "newpassword")
doc.save()
```

You will find a random hash saved in your password field, and not "newpassword"

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I think I have a grasp of isModified now and how to further search on the topic on regards to updating documents and user/password schemas.